# Is not having local functions a micro optimisation?

Tags: javascript, micro-optimization

Would moving the inner function outside of this one so that its not created everytime the function is called be a micro-optimisation?

In this particular case the `doMoreStuff` function is only used inside `doStuff`. Should I worry about having local functions like these?

```
function doStuff() {
    var doMoreStuff = function(val) {
         // do some stuff
    }

    // do something
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
         doMoreStuff(list[i]);
         for (var  j = 0; j < list[i].children.length; j++) {
              doMoreStuff(list[i].children[j]);
         }
    }
    // do some other stuff

}
```

An actaul example would be say :

```
function sendDataToServer(data) {
    var callback = function(incoming) {
         // handle incoming
    }

    ajaxCall("url", data, callback);

}
```

Comment: probably. but there are other considerations as well - in this example, the closure you create by the function being inside is invaluable, it allows you to encapsulate all other local variables you have without having to pass them as parameters or reprocess something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this falls under the category "micro-optimization". I would say no.

But it depends on how often you call `doStuff`. If you call it often, then creating the function over and over again is just unnecessary and will definitely add overhead.

If you don't want to have the "helper function" in global scope but avoid recreating it, you can wrap it like so:

```
var doStuff = (function() {
    var doMoreStuff = function(val) {
         // do some stuff
    }
    return function() {
        // do something
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            doMoreStuff(list[i]);
        }
        // do some other stuff 
    }
}());
```

As the function which is returned is a closure, it has access to `doMoreStuff`. Note that the outer function is immediately executed ( `(function(){...}())` ).

Or you create an object that holds references to the functions:

```
var stuff = {
    doMoreStuff: function() {...},
    doStuff: function() {...}
};
```

---

More information about encapsulation, object creation patterns and other concepts can be found in the book [***JavaScript Patterns***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596806752).

Comment: That's a very interesting concept. Using closures to make it act like it's static and private.

Comment: @Raynos: Yes, it is often used to encapsulate data, define private members of objects, etc. Depending on how familiar you are with JavaScript, I recommend the book [`JavaScript Patterns`](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752).

Comment: I'm familiar with the second one but "inlining" functions by using closures like that is something new to me.

Answer (score 2):

The original question was asked in 2011. Given the rise of Node.js since then, I thought it's worth revisiting the issue. In a server environment, a few milliseconds here and there can matter a lot. It could be difference between remaining responsive under load or not.

While inner functions are nice conceptually, they can pose problems for the JavaScript engine's code optimizer. The following example illustrate this:

```
function a1(n) {
    return n + 2;
}

function a2(n) {
    return 2 - n;
}

function a() {
    var k = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        k = a1(k) + a2(k);
    }
    return k;
}

function b() {
    function b1(n) {
        return n + 2;
    }

    function b2(n) {
        return 2 - n;
    }

    var k = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
        k = b1(k) + b2(k);
    }
    return k;
}

function measure(label, fn) {
    var s = new Date();
    var r = fn();
    var e = new Date();
    console.log(label, e - s);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    measure('A', a);
    measure('B', b);
}
```

The command for running the code:

```
node --trace_deopt test.js
```

The output:

```
[deoptimize global object @ 0x2431b35106e9]
A 128
B 130
A 132
[deoptimizing (DEOPT eager): begin 0x3ee3d709a821 b (opt #5) @4, FP to SP delta: 72]
  translating b => node=36, height=32
    0x7fffb88a9960: [top + 64] <- 0x2431b3504121 ; rdi 0x2431b3504121 <undefined>
    0x7fffb88a9958: [top + 56] <- 0x17210dea8376 ; caller's pc
    0x7fffb88a9950: [top + 48] <- 0x7fffb88a9998 ; caller's fp
    0x7fffb88a9948: [top + 40] <- 0x3ee3d709a709; context
    0x7fffb88a9940: [top + 32] <- 0x3ee3d709a821; function
    0x7fffb88a9938: [top + 24] <- 0x3ee3d70efa71 ; rcx 0x3ee3d70efa71 <JS Function b1 (SharedFunctionInfo 0x361602434ae1)>
    0x7fffb88a9930: [top + 16] <- 0x3ee3d70efab9 ; rdx 0x3ee3d70efab9 <JS Function b2 (SharedFunctionInfo 0x361602434b71)>
    0x7fffb88a9928: [top + 8] <- 5 ; rbx (smi)
    0x7fffb88a9920: [top + 0] <- 0 ; rax (smi)
[deoptimizing (eager): end 0x3ee3d709a821 b @4 => node=36, pc=0x17210dec9129, state=NO_REGISTERS, alignment=no padding, took 0.203 ms]
[removing optimized code for: b]
B 1000
A 125
B 1032
A 132
B 1033
```

As you can see, function A and B ran at the same speed initially. Then for some reason a deoptimization event occurred. From then on B is nearly an order of magnitude slower.

If you're writing code where performance is importantly, it's best to avoid inner functions.

Answer (score 2):

For optimal speed with a nested function (function within internal scope of an outer function), I suspect you should use **declarations**, not expressions.

The question asks about "local functions" and optimization, but doesn't specify how the local functions are created.  But it should, because the question's answer probably is different for the different techniques by which the "inner function" can be created.

Looking at the answer and test results by @cleong, I suspect that only his answer is using the optimal technique for function creation.  There are three ways to create a function, and @cleong is showing us the one that provides fast execution.  The three techniques are:

- constructor
- declaration
- expression

**Constructor** isn't used much, it requires a string that has the text of the function body.  This would be useful in reflective programming, where you do a "toString()" to get the function body, modify, then construct a new function.  And that, of course, is more-or-less never done.

**Declaration** is used, but mostly for outer functions, not inner functions (by "inner function" I mean a function nested within another).  Yet, based upon @cleong tests, it seems to be very fast; just as fast as an outer function.

**Expressions** are what everyone uses.  This might not be the best idea; but it's what everyone does.

One major difference between function declarations and function expressions is that the declarations are subject to hoisting.  Everyone knows that "var" declarations are hoisted; but so are "function" declarations.  For things that are hoisted, computations are performed at compile time to determine the memory space that will be needed for the thing.  Presumably, one would expect that the inner function is compiled at compile time, and can run much as would a compiled outer function.

I have a copy of Flannigan's "The Definitive Guide" book from about six years ago, and I remember reading the reverse of what I just wrote here.  He said something like: expressions are compiled, and declarations are not.  While he is the world's "definitive guide" to JavaScript, I have always suspected he might have gotten this one mixed up and backwards.  I suspect that function inner declarations are more "ready to go" than are function expressions.  The test results on this stackOverflow page seem to confirm my long held suspicions.

Looking at the @cleong test results, it just seems that declaration, not expression, is the way to go for inner functions, if optimal execution speed is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on how often the function is called. If it's a OnUpdate function that is called 10 times per second it is a decent optimalisation. If it's called three times per page, it is a micro optimalisation.

Though handy, nested function definitions are never needed (they can be replaced by extra arguments for the function).

Example with nested function:

```
function somefunc() {
    var localvar = 5

    var otherfunc = function() {
         alert(localvar);
    }

    otherfunc();
}
```

Same thing, now with argument instead:

```
function otherfunc(localvar) {
    alert(localvar);
}

function somefunc() {
    var localvar = 5

    otherfunc(localvar);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how I can avoid nested functions. I mainly use them to keep the code DRY and because having them outside of that particular function just adds more to global namespace where it really aught to be local. Ideally I want a static function but that's not possible.

Comment: The reason I want the local functions is mainly to contain `otherfunc` inside `somefunc` because it's only used there and inlining it gets a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely a micro-optimization.  The whole reason for having functions in the first place is so that you make your code cleaner, more maintainable and more readable.  Functions add a semantic boundary to sections of code.  Each function should only do one thing, and it should do it cleanly.  So if you find your functions performing multiple things at the same time, you've got a candidate for refactoring it into multiple routines.

Only optimize when you've got something working that's too slow (If it's not working yet, it's too early to optimize.  Period).  Remember, nobody ever paid extra for a program that was faster than their needs/requirements...

**Edit**: Considering that the program isn't finished yet, it's also a premature optimization.  Why is that bad?  Well, first you're spending time working on something that may not matter in the long run.  Second, you don't have a baseline to see if your optimizations improved anything in a realistic sense.  Third, you're reducing maintainability and readability before you've even got it running, so it'll be harder to get running than if you went with clean concise code.  Fourth, you don't know if you'll need `doMoreStuff` somewhere else in the program until you've finished it and understand all your needs (perhaps a longshot depending on the exact details, but not outside the realm of possibility).

There's a reason that Donnald Knuth said *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*...

Answer (score 0):

A quick "benchmark" run on an average PC (i know there are lots of unaccounted-for variables, so dont comment on the obvious, but it's interesting in any case):

```
count = 0;
t1 = +new Date();
while(count < 1000000) {
  p = function(){};
  ++count;
}
t2 = +new Date();
console.log(t2-t1); // milliseconds
```

It could be optimised by moving the increment to the condition for example (brings running time down by about 100 milliseconds, although it doesn't affect the *difference* between with and without function creation, so it isn't really relevant)

Running 3 times gave:

```
913
878
890
```

Then comment out the function creation line, 3 runs gave:

```
462
458
464
```

So purely on 1000,000 empty function creations you add about half a second. Even assuming your original code is running 10 times a second on a handheld device (let's say that devices overall performance is 1/100 of this laptop, which is exaggerated - it's probably closer to 1/10, although will provide a nice upper bound), that's equivalent to 1000 function creations/sec on this computer, which happens in 1/2000 of a second. So every second the handheld device is adding overhead of 1/2000 second of processing... half a millisecond every second isn't very much.

From this primitive test I would conclude that on a PC this is definitely a micro-optimisation, and if you're developing for weaker devices, it is almost certainly as well.

Comment: And if you compare it with a function body or loop body that does meaningful computation the difference lies in the boundary of statistical error on the dates.

Comment: @Raynos, i dont know how much benchmarking you've done, although testing with a larger loop body would defeat the purpose. if you keep the loop body minimal you can more accurately measure the effect of function creation, thereby_minimising_ the effect of date errors. that plus the fact that you run the test many times and you get an accurate measure. my point is that the loop body doesnt matter, your question is essentially, how much can i save by changing my code, and the answer lies in how much time creating the functions cost, which is best measured as i described.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that I thought it was a slightly meaningful optimisation. I doesn't really save much. I always thought it was bad practice.