# Javascript nested function performance

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have some nested functions such as

```
var freak = function() {
    var die = function() { ... }
    die(this);
}
```

As far as I have learned, the `die` function will get created (allocated) each time `freak` is called.

So if `freak` gets called a lot of time, that means a lot of memory will be wasted (assuming `die` is not using anything from `freak`'s context; in other words, it works fine even if it was allocated only once and shared between multiple calls of `freak` – this is what I meant with *wasted*).

Is my understanding correct? And does that mean nested functions should be avoided entirely?

Comment: This is not broad. It is very specific & practical...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> As far as I have learned, the `die` function will get created (allocated) each time `freak` is called.

Yes. This is true. A new function-object is created.

> So if `freak` gets called a lot of time, that means a lot of memory will be wasted [...]

For some *very small and normally inconsequential* value of "wasted".

JavaScript engines are very efficient these days and can perform a wide variety of tricks/optimizations.

For instance, only the function-object (but *not* the actual function code!) needs to be "duplicated" internally.

> [...] does that mean nested functions should be avoided entirely?

No. There is **no** *"wasting" problem* without an *actual* test-case that shows otherwise. This idiom (of nested and anonymous functions) is *very common* in JavaScript and very well-optimized for.

Nested functions provide many benefits including self-documenting code, smaller self-contained lexical scopes, and other code isolation/organization advantages.

Comment: +1 It's also worth noting that in the OPs example the die function will be immediately garbage collected when freak() returns since no outside reference was created, so only one instance will ever exist at a time ( in this and similar  cases ).

Comment: "immediately garbage collected" - I don't think so; at least not in every browser.  I do work with V8.NET, and the V8 engine only runs the native GC to collect objects when the host goes idle.  In fact, C#.NET also doesn't bother to collect until memory gets low (or you force it).  I believe V8, for performance reasons, only collects also when the memory gets lower (based on some threshold).

Comment: What about functions defined in an arrow notation (ie, const f = () => { ... } ) - is the overhead 'very small and normally inconsequential' in that case also ?

Comment: @kofifus The same general optimizations can be applied; furthermore, arrow functions may avoid an additional `this` binding (it turns into a potential capture vs. an invocation artifact). Outside of the most critical code / degenerate cases, functions are fair fair fair game. (Devices are also continuously become faster.)