# Node / Express define functions inside callbacks / router or outside?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback

I am using Node and express and I have an issue which I am coming across.  Frequently I need to execute a callback function, when a certain route is hit for instance.

If I have to call say, 10 functions inside that callback, should I define those functions "up op" (outside of the callback) or define them inside the callback?

It's seems that defining them inside the callback, while a bit easier (because all variables would be defined) would be less efficient because they would be defined each time the callback is called but I am not sure about this.

For example:

```
var express = require('express');
var Products = require('../products.js');
var router = express.Router();                                                                                                                                                                                                          
// Should the function "getItem" be defined here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

router.post('/', function (req, res) {                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  var info;                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  var databaseUser;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  var totalCost = 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

 // Or defined here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  function getItem (skunumber, callback) {                                                                                                                                                                                              
    Products.findOne({sku: skunumber}, function (err, product) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      product = product.toObject();                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      totalCost += product.price;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      callback = callback || function () {console.log(product.price);};                                                                                                                                                                 
      callback();                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  }
}
```

Or does it even make a difference?

Comment: These seem to be some model/business based calls, why not separate these into separate file or object/class. This would enable more easier way to write tests?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Aren't they separated into the `Products` object?

Comment: You can create a new file (products.controller.js) for instance and move the `getItem` function into that file. You can then import this file into your server.js module.

Comment: > "Aren't they separated into the Products object? " - yes and if these functions are all related to Products I would add that query logic to there, if not create another separate "model" file.

Comment: @Startec I feel you should define your function outside the callback because if you are not careful it would lead to callback hell. You can check out [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help manage your asynchronous functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is not having local functions a micro optimisation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747581/is-not-having-local-functions-a-micro-optimisation)

Comment: All very helpful. @gnerkus if I did that though, how would I manage the `totalCost` variable, which is not defined until the post request is made?

Comment: I am not sure what's missing but why not pass in as an argument to? `function getItem (skunumber, callback)` ?